# Python bytes convert

Tags: python, byte

I have a confused in processing byte.

My code background is about rs485 communication with current meter.

hex_string is command sent to meter.

I want to bytes convert to string deal recv,
trying to use recv.decode("utf-8") this method,but is invalid.

This is variable of recv content:

b'\x05\x03\x03\x00\x15\x88K' (bytes)  -> 
0503020015884b (hex)

I want to deal with this paragraph: 0503020015884b (hex) .

Remove 050302 and 884b, keep the middle 0015 and convert 0015 to decimal.

How should i do ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7
import serial,time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(40,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(40,GPIO.LOW)

ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyS0',baurdate=9600,parity='N',bytesize=8,stopbits=2,timeout=1)
hex_string = '0503010000018472'
print ('\nType-hex_string',type(hex_string))

ser.reset_input_buffer()
ser.reset_output_buffer()

GPIO.output(40,GPIO.HIGH)

ser.write(bytes.fromehex(hex_string))
time.sleep(0.01)
GPIO.output(40,GPIO.LOW)
recv = ser.read(11)

print ('\nOrigin:',recv)
print ('\nType-Origin:,'type(recv))
print ('\nHex:',recv.hex())
print ('\nType-recv.hex():',type(recv))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`struct.unpack()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack):

```
from struct import unpack

src = b'\x05\x03\x03\x00\x15\x88K'
res = unpack('>H', src[3: 5]))  # remove '>' if byte order is little endian
```

Also you can use [`struct.unpack_from()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack_from):

```
res = unpack_from('>H', src, 3)
```

You can use [`int.from_bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes):

```
res = int.from_bytes(src[3: 5], byteorder='big')
```

Comment: Hello,About this "res = unpack('>H', src[3: 5]))", I couldn't understand '>H',what's your mean ?

Comment: @Rain, I've aded link to docs in post. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters) is a table with explanation what `'H'` is. And [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) is table which will help you to understand what `'>'` does.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the bytes array as `recv` you can convert the required parts to integer by:

```
int(recv.hex()[6:10],16)
```

where 6 and 10 is the range where you have the required value.

Comment: Why to not slice source instead?

Comment: I went with this because the author wanted a solution on splitting the hex and not the source.

Comment: I mean, why not `recv[3: 5].hex()`?

Comment: recv.hex()[6:10] this is recv convert to hex and select from 3 to 5 ?
How about 16 this one ?

Comment: @Rain, [`hex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray.hex) converts `bytes` to `str` with it's hex representation. `[6: 10]` is [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) operation which returns substring from index 6 to index 9. `16` is parameter of [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) function. [Hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) is a positional system with base **16**.